# When is the init method called of a StatefulWidget called

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having a tough time understanding when the init method of a State Widget is called.

Suppose I have the following Widget

```
class FooWidget extends StatefulWidget
{
    FooWidget(this._title)
    {
        //----------->A
    }

    String _title;
    @override
    FooWidgetState createState() => new FooWidgetState();
}

class FooWidgetState extends State<FooWidget>
{

    FooWidgetState();          //----------->B

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();      //----------->C
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
                                //------>D
    }
```

I noticed that the first time `FooWidget` is created A,B,C,D are all called. However when the parent of `FooWidget` rebuilds then only A and D are called.Is this observation correct ? Why does this happen and how do I know when B and C wont be called ? When would the `init` method of `FooWidgetState` be called again ?

Answer (score 3):

The `initState` of a `State` is called only once for its whole life (basically until `dispose` is called).

So the short answer would be: `initState` and the constructor are called whenever a `State` is created, and that's it.

---

The long story is that there are a few ways to tell the framework that the `State` instance should be replaced with a new one.

When a `StatefulWidget` is updated, Flutter internally check two things:

- `widget.runtimeType`
- `widget.key`

If any of these don't match with the previous widget it means that we want to unmount the old widget and remount a new one.

As such, assigning a `UniqueKey` to a widget within the build method will cause its descendant to always destroy and recreate their `State`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SomeStatefulWidget(
    key: UniqueKey(),
  );
}
```